# Wacom Tablet not recognized in Horus

Tags: hardware

I'm getting a bunch of stuff reconnected after a house move.

I've got a Wacom Intuous Pro Small tablet. I've plugged the dongle into the desktop and actuated the tablet by pressing on one of the buttons, but EOS doe not see the tablet.

Thoughts?